# smoothing irregularly sampled time data

Tags: python, datetime, data-mining, smoothing

Given a table where the first column is seconds past a certain reference point and the second one is an arbitrary measurement:

```
6   0.738158581
21  0.801697222
39  1.797224596
49  2.77920469
54  2.839757536
79  3.832232283
91  4.676794376
97  5.18244704
100 5.521878863
118 6.316630137
131 6.778507504
147 7.020395216
157 7.331607129
176 7.637492223
202 7.848079136
223 7.989456499
251 8.76853608
278 9.092367123 
    ...
```

As you see, the measurements are sampled at irregular time points. I need to smooth the data by averaging the reading up to 100 seconds prior each measurement (in Python). Since the data table is huge, an iterator-based method is really preferred. 
Unfortunately, after two hours of coding I can't figure out efficient and elegant solution.

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**s

1. I want one smoothed reading for each raw reading, and the smoothed reading is to be the arithmetic mean of the raw reading and any others in the previous 100 (delta) seconds. (John, you are right)
2. Huge ~ 1e6 - 10e6 lines + need to work with tight RAM
3. The data is approximately random walk
4. The data is sorted

## RESOLUTION

I have tested solutions proposed by J Machin and yairchu. They both gave the same results, however, on my data set, J Machin's version performs exponentially, while that of yairchu is linear. Following are execution times as measured by IPython's *%timeit* (in microseconds):

```
data size   J Machin    yairchu
10        90.2        55.6
50          930         258
100         3080        514
500         64700       2660
1000        253000      5390
2000        952000      11500
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: is it too huge to be handled in numpy arrays ? How many items do you have ?

Comment: Is this linear interpolation to find points that are multiples of 100?

Comment: If you have smoothing requirements, please elaborate a bit more. I tried a couple of times but I cannot parse this description of yours: "I need to smooth the data by averaging the reading up to 100 seconds prior each measurement".

Comment: Please publish a little more information on your benchmark. AFAICT that behaviour (much more quadratic than exponential!) would only happen if the time values were not ascending, or were tiny positive such that the window included all or most of the readings to date. My benchmarks achieve linear results at about 60% of Y's speed with code as published, with my speed doubled to 120% of Y's speed if sum() is abandoned in favour of incremental adjustments to the total and count. Note: answers same to 14 sig dec digits.

Comment: CONTINUED: I used max(0.1, random.normalvariate(mu=16.0, sigma=7.81)) to generate random positive time intervals; the 0.1 was to avoid any negatives and the 16.0000000 :-) and the 7.81 were fitted from your sample. Initially I was getting quadratic behaviour until I noticed I'd put min instead of max! BTW as you said random walk, I used new_reading = old_reading + random.random().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using a sum result to which I'm adding the new members and subtracting the old ones. However in this way one may suffer accumulating floating point inaccuracies.

Therefore I implement a "Deque" with a list. And whenever my Deque reallocates to a smaller size. I recalculate the sum at the same occasion.

I'm also calculating the average up to point x including point x so there's at least one sample point to average.

```
def getAvgValues(data, avgSampleTime):
  lastTime = 0
  prevValsBuf = []
  prevValsStart = 0
  tot = 0
  for t, v in data:
    avgStart = t - avgSampleTime
    # remove too old values
    while prevValsStart < len(prevValsBuf):
      pt, pv = prevValsBuf[prevValsStart]
      if pt > avgStart:
        break
      tot -= pv
      prevValsStart += 1
    # add new item
    tot += v
    prevValsBuf.append((t, v))
    # yield result
    numItems = len(prevValsBuf) - prevValsStart
    yield (t, tot / numItems)
    # clean prevVals if it's time
    if prevValsStart * 2 > len(prevValsBuf):
      prevValsBuf = prevValsBuf[prevValsStart:]
      prevValsStart = 0
      # recalculate tot for not accumulating float precision error
      tot = sum(v for (t, v) in prevValsBuf)
```

Comment: (1) That's a very interesting implementation of a deque. (2) I doubt that the OP is very worried about floating point rounding errors accumulating; they'd surely be very small cuts compared with the severe changes of the smoothing ... but if he is, using a Kahan adder to maintain the running total could be considered.

Comment: Note that this is very computationally intensive as compared to an exponential moving average (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023860/exponential-moving-average-sampled-at-varying-times/1024008). Unless you particularly need the make sure that all samples within the time range contribute equally, and older ones do not contribute at all, I'd go with the much more efficient EMA.

Comment: @Curt Sampson: the OP particularly asked for this

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said exactly when you want output. I'm assuming that you want one smoothed reading for each raw reading, and the smoothed reading is to be the arithmetic mean of the raw reading and any others in the previous 100 (delta) seconds.

Short answer: use a collections.deque ... it will never hold more than "delta" seconds of readings. The way I've set it up you can treat the deque just like a list, and easily calculate the mean or some fancy gizmoid that gives more weight to recent readings.

Long answer:

```
>>> the_data = [tuple(map(float, x.split())) for x in """\
... 6       0.738158581
... 21      0.801697222
[snip]
... 251     8.76853608
... 278     9.092367123""".splitlines()]
>>> import collections
>>> delta = 100.0
>>> q = collections.deque()
>>> for t, v in the_data:
...     while q and q[0][0] <= t - delta:
...         # jettison outdated readings
...         _unused = q.popleft()
...     q.append((t, v))
...     count = len(q)
...     print t, sum(item[1] for item in q) / count, count
...
...
6.0 0.738158581 1
21.0 0.7699279015 2
39.0 1.112360133 3
49.0 1.52907127225 4
54.0 1.791208525 5
79.0 2.13137915133 6
91.0 2.49500989771 7
97.0 2.8309395405 8
100.0 3.12993279856 9
118.0 3.74976297144 9
131.0 4.41385300278 9
147.0 4.99420529389 9
157.0 5.8325615685 8
176.0 6.033109419 9
202.0 7.15545189083 6
223.0 7.4342562845 6
251.0 7.9150342134 5
278.0 8.4246097095 4
>>>
```

**Edit**

One-stop shop: get your fancy gizmoid here. Here's the code:

```
numerator = sum(item[1] * upsilon ** (t - item[0]) for item in q)
denominator = sum(upsilon ** (t - item[0]) for item in q)
gizmoid = numerator / denominator
```

where upsilon should be a little less than 1.0 (<= zero is illegal, just above zero does little smoothing, one gets you the arithmetic mean plus wasted CPU time, and greater than one gives the inverse of your purpose).

Comment: It seems to me a regular list would work here, using .pop(0) instead of .popleft().   What is the advantage of collections.deque?

Comment: popping the left of a Python list is O(N); popping the left of a deque is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be roughly linear:

[Plot of your data http://rix0r.nl/~rix0r/share/shot-20090621.144851.gif](http://rix0r.nl/~rix0r/share/shot-20090621.144851.gif)

What kind of smoothing are you looking for? A least squares fit of a line to this data set? Some sort of low-pass filter? Or something else?

Please tell us the application so we can advise you a bit better.

EDIT: For example, depending on the application, interpolating a line between the first and last point may be good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This one makes it linear:

```
def process_data(datafile):
    previous_n = 0
    previous_t = 0
    for line in datafile:
        t, number = line.strip().split()
        t = int(t)
        number = float(number)
        delta_n = number - previous_n
        delta_t = t - previous_t
        n_per_t = delta_n / delta_t
        for t0 in xrange(delta_t):
            yield previous_t + t0, previous_n + (n_per_t * t0)
        previous_n = n
        previous_t = t

f = open('datafile.dat')

for sample in process_data(f):
    print sample
```

Comment: (1) The .strip() is redundant. (2) You appear to have forgotten to update previous_* each time around (3) Even then, it's not apparent what this is meant to do ... it would appear to do a linear interpolation between the previous reading and the current reading, at one second intervals -- an interesting interpretation of the OP's requirements. (3) I think you meant `for t0 in xrange(1, delta_t + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

O(1) memory in case you can iterate the input more than once - you can use one iterator for the "left" and one for the "right".

```
def getAvgValues(makeIter, avgSampleTime):
  leftIter = makeIter()
  leftT, leftV = leftIter.next()
  tot = 0
  count = 0
  for rightT, rightV in makeIter():
    tot += rightV
    count += 1
    while leftT <= rightT - avgSampleTime:
      tot -= leftV
      count -= 1
      leftT, leftV = leftIter.next()
    yield rightT, tot / count
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants to display the smoothed value in real time ... think heart-beat monitor in the intensive care ward.

Answer (score 0):

While it gives an exponentially decaying average, rather than a total average, I think you may want what I called an [exponential moving average with varying alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023860/exponential-moving-average-sampled-at-varying-times), which is really a single-pole low-pass filter. There's now a solution to that question, and it runs in time linear to the number of data points. See if it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

what about something like this, keep storing values till time difference with last time is > 100, average and yield such values
e.g.

```
def getAvgValues(data):
    lastTime = 0
    prevValues = []
    avgSampleTime=100

    for t, v in data:
        if t - lastTime < avgSampleTime:
            prevValues.append(v)
        else:
            avgV = sum(prevValues)/len(prevValues)
            lastTime = t
            prevValues = [v]
            yield (t,avgV)

for v in getAvgValues(data):
    print v
```

Comment: he asked for averages of previous 100 seconds for all the times of original measurements. you give only 2 results for his example

Comment: hmm i misunderstood it, any way looks like you modified it for correct solution

Comment: I didn't modify it really. I just used your variable names.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you need a simple rounding formula. To round any number to an arbitrary interval:

round(num/interval)*interval

You can substitute round with floor or ceiling for "leading up to" or "since" affects. It can work in any language, including SQL.